# Hello. I have a problem with a smart contract transaction between users. Error: gas is missing

Tags: web3js, javascript

I have a problem with a smart contract transaction between users. Error: gas is missing.

Here is my function:

```
async function transactionContract() {
  
  let signerAddress = gettingOwnerByKey(
    "privateKey"
  ).address;

 
  let addressRecipient = "0x82A8AD5c429903c082686a307083330F99c40E53";

  const escrow = new web3.eth.Contract(
    ABI2,
    "0xF36198Ce8Dfe6A5694541bb1604195A7b9E2A61D",
    {
      from: "0x061A96C2b5A18b132783bF65a45BC720e6C95b2A",
    }
  );
  const NET_ID = "35855456";

 
  let tx = await escrow.methods.shifting(addressRecipient).encodeABI({
    chainId: NET_ID,
    gas: "320000",
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("42", "gwei"),
    nonce:  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(signerAddress, "pending"),
  });


  const signedContract = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
    tx,
    "privateKey"
  );

 
  const transactionSignature = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
    signedContract.rawTransaction
  );
  console.log(transactionSignature)
}
```

I cannot understand why it will result in an error - "gas is missing"!

Comment: What line does cause such error message? The call to `getTransactionCount` is missing await.

Comment: ` const signedContract = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
    tx,
    "privat key"
  );`   error here

Comment: Why are you assigning to tx the result of `encodeABI()`? Also it doesn't accept any parameter. Probably you wanted to do something like `let tx = { <other fields>, data: await escrow.methods.shifting(addressRecipient).encodeABI() }` instead.

Comment: If I write instead of encodeABI () - send (), an error pops up: "Unknown account".   Tx should return data object? I did as you said, as a result, tx returns an object. But the promise also returns an error: [[PromiseResult]]: Error: "gas" is missing at _validateTransactionForSigning

Comment: What are you trying to do, send a transaction or sign a transaction? If you output tx before signing what does it look like? Try writing gas as an hexadecimal string `web3.utils.toHex("3200")`.

Comment: Recording gas as a hexadecimal string didn't work, same error! Using signTransaction I sign the transaction and then using sendSignedTransaction I send the already signed transaction. The result of Tx output to the console is the following number 0x47bf68b200000000000000000000000082a8ad5c429903c082686a307083330f99c40e53. After you told me to do this let tx = {<other fields>, data: await escrow.methods.shifting (addressRecipient) .encodeABI ()} the output to the console is {data: "0x47bf68b200000000000000000000000082a8ad5c429903c082686a304083330f99c"} + object properties specified in tx

Comment: I have a smart contract, it belongs to my wallet. The result of my function should be - transfer of ownership of this smart contract to another wallet

Comment: It seems that I am doing everything right, but I do not understand why the "gas" is missing error appears

Comment: All appears to be fine, the only other thing I'd check is the networkId.

Comment: and what exactly needs to be checked? He's correct everything fits together. Are there any other solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
const recipient = new web3.eth.Contract(<ABI>, <address>);

const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(signerAddress, "pending");
const data = recipient.methods.deposit(4444).encodeABI();

const txData = {
    chainId: web3.utils.toHex('35855456'),
    nonce,
    from: signerAddress,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("42", "gwei"),
    gas: web3.utils.toHex('320000'),
    to: recipient.options.address,
    value: '0x',
    data
};

const tx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txData, privateKey);

await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(tx.rawTransaction);

const id = await recipient.methods.id().call();

console.log(`Id: ${id}`);
```

Where my test contract is

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Recipient {
  uint public id;

  function deposit(uint _id) public payable {
    id = _id;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am the owner of a smart contract, I need to transfer the ownership of my smart contract to another wallet. I tried to do it according to your example, the transaction hash is formed, but it displays Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Comment: /* my smart contract the ownership of which I want to transfer */
const recipient = new web3.eth.Contract(
  ABI2,
  "0xF36198Ce8Dfe6A5694541bb1604195A7b9E2A61D"
);

Comment: /* contract owner */
let signerAddress = gettingOwnerByKey(
  "private key"
).address;

Comment: /* I want this to be the new owner of my smart contract */
let addressRecipient = "0x82A8AD5c429903c082686a307083330F99c40E53";

Comment: /* shifting (addressRecipient) using this method, the rights to own the smart contract are transferred */
const data = recipient.methods.shifting(addressRecipient).encodeABI();

Comment: @АртемСтрекалов That is a completely different problem. Please create a new question. Be aware that to analyze such error you will need to provide source code, transaction details like data field and failed transaction hash. Without those details the only possible answeer is that there's an error in the contract.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new question with a detailed description of my problem and with two ways to implement the question.  (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92144/i-have-a-problem-with-the-transfer-of-ownership-by-a-smart-contract)